# Can I get by with a single privateQueueConcurrencyType managed object context and no MOC for the main queue?

Tags: core-data, swift4.2, ios9.3

I have read plenty of info about code using a main thread managed object context and a lot about having private parents, children, and siblings for various reasons. I would like to know if there is any requirement to have more than a single private-queue managed object context that is set to use a "disk" based persistent store coordinator. I have almost no code in my app that will use the core data entities for updating the UI directly so anything more than a private-queue MOC seems excessive. My code will be happy to wait in the main thread for a background thread to get what little data it needs.